# Как составить запрос где параметры в условиях WHERE участовали бы опционально?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как сделать так, чтобы в процедуру можно было передавать какие-то параметры, и в клаузе `WHERE` те параметры, которые не были переданы опускались бы (не участвовали в условии поиска).

Неужели надо писать огромный `IF ELSE`?

```
USE master;
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAuction
        @inNumber NVARCHAR(max),
        @inBankGuaranteeNumber nvarchar(50),            

        @Id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
        @Number NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT, --Номер аукциона
        @BankGuaranteeNumber nvarchar(50) OUTPUT --Номер банковской гарантии
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Auctions
    WHERE Number = @inNumber AND
          BankGuaranteeNumber = @inBankGuaranteeNumber
END;
```

**UPDATED**:
Пользуясь советом [@nick-n-a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780655/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-where-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb/1128777#comment1224015_780655) переписал запрос таким образом:

```
USE master;
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAuction
        @inNumber NVARCHAR(max) = null,
        @inBankGuarantee nvarchar(50) = null,            

        @Id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
        @Number NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT, --Номер аукциона
        @BankGuarantee nvarchar(50) OUTPUT --Номер банковской гарантии
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Auctions
    WHERE (@inNumber is null or Number = @inNumber) AND
          (@inBankGuarantee is null or BankGuarantee = @inBankGuarantee)
END;
```

Если я все верно понимаю, то не передавая ни одного параметра в процедуру, я просто получу все записи?

Comment: Можно писать `(@inNumber is null or Number=@inNumber)` и т д.

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: или `Number = IsNull(@inNumber, Number)`, что чуть-чуть короче

Comment: Я обычно  через decode делаю (в Oracle), в MS SQL Server iif аналог. Как-то так: `iif(@inNumber is null,Number,@inNumber) = Number`. Выше предложили через `ISNULL`, но ведь по умолчанию может быть, например, 0, а не NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь входящим в SQL стандарт [COALESCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), коротко и понятно:

```
[...]
WHERE coalesce (@inNumber, Number) = Number AND 
      coalesce (@inBankGuarantee, BankGuarantee) = BankGuarantee
```

> не передавая ни одного параметра в процедуру, я просто получу все записи?

Да.